# Move div to bottom of the screen with css transform

Tags: html, css

I want to move a div to the bottom of the screen.
The translate property only moves the div in relation to its size:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>

html, body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(0,100%);
  background: blue;
}
```

This will move the div downwards by 100% of it's height (25% of the screen).
How can I move the div to the bottom of the screen?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXWGAm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `vh` instead of `%`, that way it moves it 75% down the height of the screen, leaving the other 25% for your div.

I would also recommend you change the height of your div to `25vh` to ensure that it sits on the bottom.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 75vh);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `transform: translate(0, calc(100vh - 25%))` can't assume that `%` is same to `vh`.

Comment: @Mr_Green good point - so I've added a comment saying it would be better to change height from 25% to 25vh

Comment: You will find issues with vh on mobile as chrome at least includes the address bar as part of 100vh

Answer (score 1):

Using `position:absolute` is the best way like this

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But as you specifically need `transform` use this

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
  transform:translate(0,75vh);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> As your height is fixed to `25%` no problem to using `75vh`

Comment: As I stated, i want to use transform: translate();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` and make `bottom:0px`; instead of transform property.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: As I stated, i want to use transform: translate();

Comment: is there any parent of that div?

Answer (score 0):

Do you like this,

Html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test{
 position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0,100%);
  background: blue;
}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/17d80ym3/19/